# How to get Data from relational database codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As i was using comma separated values in DB every one suggested me to normalize table so i normalized my table now my table looks like this

```
tuitor table
tuitor_id | name | mobile |etc
   1      | xyz  |14562547|anyinputs
   2      |abc   |47545875|text
   3      |abd   |47854874|yyy

now my normalized table is tuitor_keyword

tuitor_keyword_id | id_tuitor | id_keyword
   1              |   1       |123
   2              |   1       |124
   3              |   2       |123
   4              |   2       |155
   5              |   1       |187
```

while retrieving any tuitor i want keywords in comma like for id_tuitor=1 it should be 123,124

```
this is the query what i am using

        $this->db->select('*')->from('tuitor');  
        $this->db->join('tuitor_keyword','tuitor.tuitor_id =  tuitor_keyword.id_tuitor','left');

  $query=$this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result_array();
```

It is creating new array for for tuitor_keyword_id what should i do please correct me i know i have done plenty of mistakes

Comment: Your question is unclear, What input you will give and what is the output you want?

Comment: i have normalized my table now i want to retrieve data to view leave  $search  = "FIND_IN_SET('".$toteach."', id_keyword)"; just i want to retrieve data in view where keywors should come with commas

Comment: @Alok in view it should come in single array

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT_GROUP is a solution for you:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT id_tuitor, CONCAT_GROUP(id_keyword) AS gr FROM tuitor_keyword GROUP BY id_tuitor');
```

or:

```
$this->db->select('id_tuitor, CONCAT_GROUP(id_keyword) AS gr', false)->from('tuitor_keyword')->group_by('id_tuitor');
```

Comment: @PaweIN it is showing Not unique table/alias: 'tuitor_keyword'

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code what I wrote above or you added sth else?

Comment: yes but few more joins are there like $this->db->join('city_tuitor', 'tuitor.city_tutor = city_tuitor.city_id', 'left');

Comment: so u need to define unique aliases for columns and tables if any of them repeats

Comment: tuitor_keyword_id this is unique in tuitor_keyword table where should i use it @paweIN

Comment: pls, provide us full database query... without it we cant help more